# adding gesturerecongnizer programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i know how to add a gesture recognizer via the IB but I'm trying to figure it out with out using IB.

So basically what have right now is

```
blue1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pgr = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                               initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];

[blue1 addGestureRecognizer:pgr];
[pgr release];
```

and my handlePan is

```
-(IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

}
```

this works fine if i do it over the IB and i am able to movie the piece around.

I dont understand what is causing it not to move like it is coded now.

Any help is appreciated.

I also tried -(void) instead of -(IBAction) in my handlePan but that didn't work either.

Comment: Where is your first code segment? Is it in the `init` method somewhere?

Comment: first code segment is in a method that gets called from viewdidload.  It's a method that i want to run as soon as view loads.

Comment: Why did you write `[pgr release];`? Were you not using ARC for this example, or is that something that is necessary when creating and adding a gesturerecognizer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that this works in IB, but not in code suggests that the error is in the first block of code. My suspicion would be that `blue1` is `nil`. Make sure that you do not try to modify views before `viewDidLoad`. They will all be `nil` in `initWithFrame:` and `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I called this method before i set another variable to true so it skipped this part since that other variable was false.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(_:)))

    myImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    myImage.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print(#function)
}
```